# span:hover elements not working for my box

Tags: css, tabs, hover, rollover

My goal is to build a box with two tabs, and have certain text in the tab show up when a user hovers over the tab. For the tabs on my box, I have made a list inside a div.

Inside the "a" tag I put in a  tag for the text I would like hidden when not hovered. In my CSS I set the span{opacity: 0} and span:hover{opacity:1}. The text is hidden, but when I hover over a  nothing happens.

Check out the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/lamike/74sBm/6/

Any suggestions?

Thanks for any feedback

Comment: You'll have to use JavaScript for this.

Comment: are you asking for the javascript? If you are you might want to consider using a framework to help you... jquery ui etc.

Comment: Have you shown the correct fiddle? I don't see any `opacty`, let alone `<span>` tags..

Comment: I updated the fiddle... My goal is to do this with just CSS and HTML is that possible? Or is the span:hover something you do in Javascript?

Comment: It is possible with just HTML/CSS in some browsers. I'm not sure about all versions of IE, but FF/Chrome should work fine with my answer below. Running Linux so testing in IE is a pain. ;)

Comment: You have opacity: 1 to both span and span: hover

Answer (score 2):

First, your fiddle is wrong - you have `opacity: 1` in both `span` and `span:hover`. Change that and it works fine - the X appears, but only when you hover over the `span` containing X. I'm guessing you want it to show up any time the tab is hovered, so try this:

```
a:hover span {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

That works for me in FF.

EDIT: Oh, and you really should use a class on the span, rather than applying the style to all spans.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your span element to change when you hover the tab, then what you need is this:

```
a:hover span {

    opacity: 1;

}
```